# Building 3D arrays in Python to replace loops for optimization

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to better understand python optimization so this is a dummy case, but hopefully outlines my idea...

Say I have a function which takes two variables:

```
def func(param1, param2):
    return some_func(param1) + some_const*(param2/2)
```

and I have arrays for param1 and param2 (of different lengths), at which I want the function to be evaluated, (some_func is an arbitrary function of param1) e.g.

```
param1 = np.array((1,2,3,4,5))
param2 = np.array((5,2,3,1,9, 9, 10))
```

I can evaluate over all parameter space by doing:

```
result = []
for p in param1:
    result.append(func(p, param2))
result = np.asarray(result)
```

However, loops in Python are slower than array operations. Therefore, I wonder is there a way to achieve a 3D array which contains the results of func for all values in both param1 and param2 arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example:

```
In [198]: result=[]
In [199]: for p in param1:
   .....:     result.append(p+3*(param2/2))
In [200]: result=np.array(result)
```

Same result using broadcasting (and `np.newaxis`):

```
In [197]: param1[:,None] + 3*(param2[None,:]/2)
Out[197]: 
array([[ 7,  4,  4,  1, 13, 13, 16],
       [ 8,  5,  5,  2, 14, 14, 17],
       [ 9,  6,  6,  3, 15, 15, 18],
       [10,  7,  7,  4, 16, 16, 19],
       [11,  8,  8,  5, 17, 17, 20]])
```

Details of `some_func` would determine whether you use `some_func(param1[:,None])` or `some_func(param1)[:,None]`.

Answer (score 3):

*Original answer for some_func(param1) x param2*

Write the `some_func` in such a way that it can accept and return numpy arrays. Then use;

```
numpy.outer(some_func(param1), param2)
```

This works because in your example, both `param1` and `param2` are *vectors* (1D arrays), so you can use `outer` and the result will be a 2D array, not 3D.

*Edit*

As long as the operation you want to do is a
[universal function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) ("ufunc"), you can use its `outer` method;

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(10)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [4]: b = np.arange(15)

In [5]: np.add.outer(a, b)
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This would work for the specific case of multiplication as I originally put in my question. In fact, I'm interested in this more generally when the function isn't a simple multiplication (e.g. return some_func(param1) + some_const*(param2/2)) as in this case I imagine np.outer would no longer work. Thanks

Comment: indeed. outer does multiplication, whereas addition is called for

Comment: @IanRoberts All universal functions support outer. See improved answer. All standard arithmatic operations are available as ufuncs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, is this essentially the same as the procedure outline in hpaulji's answer? And is there any difference in terms of memory usage of speed by using the numpy outer function rather than broadcasting and np.newaxis?

Comment: @IanRoberts I'm not sure. It could be that usinf ufunc,outer directly is faster because it looks like it uses less operations. But you'd have to test it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy broadcasting, as hpaulj suggested. This is generally the first line of attack for vectorizing numpy operations. The essence of using broadcasting, is that in doing so, you move your loops from the slow python level down to the C level.

Alternatively, you may choose to take a look at [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), and [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/), which accomplish vectorization in a more flexible manner